# Are there any restriction(s), regulations or any other internationalization issues using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) that one should be aware of?

Tags: android, firebase, internationalization, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a messaging app and we are investigating migrating from GCM to FCM. So far, so good, everything looks about the same.  Before making the switch, I wanted to confirm that none of our international users would have any issues.  Are you aware of any countries that have any kind of restriction on FCM, or push notifications in general?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Cloud Messaging and Google Cloud Messaging run on the same back-end infrastructure.

While I cannot guarantee that none of your international users will have any issues, it is very unlikely that they're related to switching from GCM to FCM.